# Limit outgoing bandwidth on an specific interface

Tags: linux, networking

I would like to know the easiest way to limit outgoing bandwidth for an interface. I want to cap the outgoing port speed so that file transfers between my servers don't fail during busy hours.

What's the easiest solution? I know I could use `iptables` but I'm looking for a simple installation/configuration.

Comment: HTB works great. Very flexible rate limiting. http://sourceforge.net/projects/htbinit/

Answer (score 41):

#### ethtool

You can change the aggregate speed of the NIC port using [`ethtool`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/ethtool).

```
$ sudo ethtool -s eth0 speed 10
```

**NOTE:** This will set the port to 10MB, for example, you cannot set an arbitrary speed using this method!

#### wondershaper

You can also use the tool [`wondershaper`](http://lartc.org/wondershaper/) to do it as well. **NOTE:** Speed should be in kilobits per second.

```
$ sudo wondershaper eth1 downspeed upspeed
```

For example:

```
$ sudo wondershaper eth0 10000 280
```

#### trickle

A 3rd option is [Trickle](http://monkey.org/%7Emarius/pages/?page=trickle). Trickle can be used per program by users or as a daemon that throttles the NIC completely.

*User mode - [trickle man page](http://monkey.org/%7Emarius/trickle/trickle.1.txt)*

```
$ sudo trickle -d 20 -u 20 wget http://www.google.com/bigfile
```

Will throttle 20K/s for both up and down traffic for just this `wget`, everything else will not be limited.

*Daemon mode - [trickled man page](http://monkey.org/%7Emarius/trickle/trickled.8.txt)*

In daemon mode, `trickled` can limit a group of programs to a fixed limit of bandwidth. To start the daemon, run the trickled command:

```
$ sudo trickled -d 20 -u 20
```

#### pyshaper

A 4th option is [pyshaper](http://freenet.mcnabhosting.com/python/pyshaper/). It's a unique option among the choices in that it includes GUI and it dynamically monitors and sets the bandwidth over time. You can check out the [pyshaper man page](http://freenet.mcnabhosting.com/python/pyshaper/pyshaper.html) for more details.

[image: pyshaper gui]

#### References

- [Use bandwidth shapers (wondershaper or trickle) to limit internet connection speed](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/use-bandwidth-shapers-wondershaper-or-trickle-to-limit-internet-connection-speed.html)

Comment: Limiting bandwidth usage of the trouble applications via cgroups would probably also be worthwhile if their kernel supports it.

Comment: wondershaper isn't working I don't know why (even` wondershaper eth0 1000 1000` has no internet bandwidth same as ` sudo trickled -d 20 -u 20`.) I need to limit One network interface. bandwidth not only specific applications. how can in do that?

Comment: trickle did not work for me, but wondershaper did the trick!

Comment: This answer should clarify that [you cannot use `ethtool` to limit bandwidth to an arbitrary speed](https://serverfault.com/a/707720/297452). The tool can change the link speed of the network adapter to one of a few link speeds that are supported by the stack, typically 10, 100, or 1000. If you want any values other than those, you need to use a different tool (I prefer `tc`).

Comment: @MaximillianLaumeister - good call, added.

Answer (score 1):

Wondershaper was last edited in 2002 but it still works on Fedora 21 today. But note, there are only a couple of options available as arguments and you cannot specify the upload/download speed on the command line as specified here- at least, not in Download version 1.1a, released 16th of April 2002. You have to edit the file, and it's a shell script. Not hard for those who know a little shell.

Usage is:

`wondershaper`    (this one will set your bandwidth according to the values in the file)

```
wondershaper status
wondershaper stop
```

You can use it while the link is up live, which is nice.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is '[iproute2](http://www.linuxfoundation.org/collaborate/workgroups/networking/iproute2)' which appears to be a mature and widely available traffic routing/shaping tool.  I found it as an RPM (probably many other packages too, I didn't look).  As of this writing, the most recent version was 4.4.0, built on 25 Jan 2016.

Looking over the configuration syntax, it appears to be relatively simple (though not as simple as `ifconfig` or `route`.)

Comment: Your answer doesn’t address how one actually would use iproute2 to limit outgoing bandwidth. Can you elaborate please?