# Is it possible to change the priority/nice values for an application's access to the NIC, giving precedence for bandwidth?

Tags: networking, network-interface, bandwidth

Is it possible to tune which applications receive the most bandwidth on a NIC, similar to the -20 to +20 Nice value but for bandwidth instead of processor-time?

Transmission seems to choke out my other applications. I can slow down the application from its options but I wondered if there was a linux/non-application-specific solution where I can view and tune everything that has network access.

**Update:**
I suspect the problem is shown in the output below. Currently all web and transmission traffic is TCP source port 80 and a dynamic destination port, and is lumped together in class 0:3 (with 16810552 bytes and 171075 packets). So, because my web connection is not that fast, transmission is choking it out just enough for me to get timeouts. The output shows that no packets are being dropped by the queuing discipline.

I'm looking at [**tcng**](http://tcng.sourceforge.net/) as a possible solution because of the configuration already present.

```
$ tc qdisc show dev wlp2s0
qdisc mq 0: root 
qdisc fq_codel 0: parent :4 limit 10240p flows 1024 quantum 1514 target 5.0ms interval 100.0ms memory_limit 32Mb ecn 
qdisc fq_codel 0: parent :3 limit 10240p flows 1024 quantum 1514 target 5.0ms interval 100.0ms memory_limit 32Mb ecn 
qdisc fq_codel 0: parent :2 limit 10240p flows 1024 quantum 1514 target 5.0ms interval 100.0ms memory_limit 32Mb ecn 
qdisc fq_codel 0: parent :1 limit 10240p flows 1024 quantum 1514 target 5.0ms interval 100.0ms memory_limit 32Mb ecn 

$ tc -g -s class show dev wlp2s0
+---(:4) mq 
|       Sent 5670 bytes 105 pkt (dropped 0, overlimits 0 requeues 1) 
|       backlog 0b 0p requeues 1
|   
+---(:3) mq 
|       Sent 16810552 bytes 171075 pkt (dropped 0, overlimits 0 requeues 0) 
|       backlog 0b 0p requeues 0   competing for bandwidth
|     
+---(:2) mq 
|       Sent 2538 bytes 31 pkt (dropped 0, overlimits 0 requeues 1) 
|       backlog 0b 0p requeues 1
|     
+---(:1) mq 
        Sent 13432 bytes 76 pkt (dropped 0, overlimits 0 requeues 0) 
        backlog 0b 0p requeues 0
```

Comment: You can do this with namespaces. I have only done this with services in docker. However it will be possible to do what you want as well. But I have not done it. (It is a feature of the Linux kernel, finding user mode tools may or may not be tricky.)

Answer (score 2):

### Traffic shaping QoS

I've historically used tools such as [Wondershaper](http://lartc.org/wondershaper/), [Trickle](http://monkey.org/~marius/pages/?page=trickle), or pyshaper to throttle network traffic.

### Examples

#### *Trickle*

To throttle the upload/download speed to 20Kbps.

```
$ trickle -d 20 wget -c http://download1.rpmfusion.org/free/fedora/rpmfusion-free-release-stable.noarch.rpm
```

You can also set these independently in the above scenario. You can also make these settings the default like so.

```
$ trickled -d 50 -u 10
```

#### *Wondershaper*

You can also use Wondershaper to control the bandwidth at the network level. For example say I want to throttle my `eth1` device.

```
$ sudo wondershaper eth1 1024 256
```

This will give me a Download speed of 1024 Kbits and 256 Kbits Upload. Which are 128KB and 16KB.

When you want to release the caps.

```
$ sudo wondershaper clear eth1
```

#### *pyshaper*

I've extensively covered `pyshaper` on the site before, see these U&L Q&As titled:

- [How to change speed limit of running trickle instance](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/109973/how-to-change-speed-limit-of-running-trickle-instance)
- [Limit outgoing bandwidth on an specific interface](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/83888/limit-outgoing-bandwidth-on-an-specific-interface/)

These are pretty capable tools so this is just meant to show you the potential.

#### References

- [How do I limit internet bandwidth?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/20872/how-do-i-limit-internet-bandwidth)
- [Control your bandwidth with Trickle](http://www.tuxradar.com/content/control-your-bandwidth-trickle)

Answer (score 1):

Probably what you are looking for is quality of service (QoS) which may not be easily available in your favorite firewall (like `iptables`, `nftables`, `pf`, `ufw`, etc) but should be simple on any modern router and operates by **IP/port**.

iptables example;
https://serverfault.com/questions/762921/qos-with-iptables-and-tc-with-unstable-wan

As slm mentioned `trickle` can be used when starting a **process** when not using commands (like `rsync`, `curl`, `wget`) which have rate limiting as a built in option.

`wondershaper` can be used to limit by **[virtual] interface** which is usefull for commands and VMs that can be bound to a nic (like `rsync`, `curl`, `wget`).